# If the capacity (cap) is 0, this trigger should delete the newly inserted tuple. what did i do wrong here? here is the code

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, database-trigger

i was making an application on oracle apex. now, If the capacity (`cap`) is `0`, this trigger should delete the newly inserted tuple because that `passenger_id` will not be valid. what did i do wrong here?

Here is the code

```
create or replace trigger Ticket_katbo
before insert on passenger 
for each row
declare 
newcap number;
cap number;
flightpk number;
begin
flightpk := :new.flight_fid;
select flight_capacity into cap from flight where fid = flightpk;
if (cap>0) THEN
newcap := cap-1;
update flight set flight_capacity = newcap where fid = flightpk ;
ELSIF (cap=0 or cap = NULL) THEN
Delete from passenger where passenger_id = :new.passenger_id;
END IF;
end;
```

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: I'd advise to create a validation on the page in apex and show an error that way instead of letting the transaction occur and catch this in a trigger per default. That's what validations are made for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this before the insert.  So raise an error if the capacity is not there:

```
create or replace trigger Ticket_katbo
before insert on passenger 
for each row
declare 
    v_capacity number;
begin
    select flight_capacity into v_capacity
    from flight
    where fid = :new.flight_fid;

    if (cap <= 0) then
        raise_application_error( -20001, 
                                 'No capacity for another passenger');
    end if;

    update flight
        set flight_capacity = flight_capacity - 1
        where fid = :new.flight_fid;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @Gordon Linoff